# Text in menu over to the side

Tags: html, css, text, navigation, alignment

I have a vertical navigation menu but can't seem to get the text to start from very left edge of the element.

### HTML

```
<div class="jobs-links">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="renovations.html">Renovations</a></li>
        <li><a href="remodelling.html">Remodelling</a></li>
        <li><a href="adding.html">Adding</a></li>
    </ul>                   </div>
```

### CSS

```
.jobs-links {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #5f564d;
    border-left:1px solid #5f564d;
    border-top:1px solid #5f564d;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Calibri, Times, serif;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:10%;
    text-align:left;
    height:120px;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:179px;
    height:30px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #5f564d;
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpEmj/)

Cheers.

Comment: Alek solved your problem, so i won't make another answer, but in future you could use "html css reset" - look for it in google. It's great starter for new layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
ul{
    padding:0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpEmj/1/)

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciated.